# SharePoint 2010 DocId for Non-Office Documents redirects to DispForm.aspx instead of Document

Tags: document

Right now we have a site collection with Document ID service enabled.

In a document library, we add a PDF or BMP files.  Initially, the DocID column in the view links directly to the file.  A few minutes later either search or another process must have run(?), and then the DocIdRedir.aspx no longer redirects the PDF to the file, it redirects to the DispForm.aspx page. Word docs still redirect normally to the file.

Any suggestions for workarounds?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, reopen this question.